# excel macro that automatically creates a new sheet that continues a "for loop" from previous sheet1

Tags: vba

I have written a vba code that has a `"for next"` loop 1 to 10 and displays the result in respective rows in ColumnA, i want when it reaches row 5 the macro should automatically create a new sheet named "New sheet" and the `"for next"` continues from 6 til it reaches 10. I'm new to VBA and the code I wrote doesn't seem to work.

My VBA code:

```
Sub test()

Dim a As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1))
WS.Name = "New Sheet"

n = 1
col1 = 1

For a = 1 To 10

    If n <= 5 Then

        Cells(n, col1).Value = a
        n = n + 1

    End If

    If n > 5 Then

        WS.Cells(n, 1).Value = a
        n = n + 1

    End If

Next a


  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be further improved if you follow [what's posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).
As for your question, you can try below:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim newWS As Worksheet
    Dim a As Long
    Dim n As Long: n = 1

    With Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetName")
        For a = 1 To 10
            If n > 5 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Set newWS = Thisworkbook.Sheets("New Sheet")
                On Error Goto 0
                If newWS Is Nothing Then
                    Set newWS = Thisworkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
                        Thisworkbook.Sheets(Thisworkbook.Sheets.Count))
                    newWS.Name = "New Sheet"
                End If
                newWS.Cells(n, 1).Value = a
            Else
                .Cells(n, 1).Value = a
            End If
            n = n + 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you L42, your help has increased my understanding of VBA